# Why is swift running so slowly in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, algorithm

The loop from 0 to 10000000 is tested with swift, js, and flutter respectively.

swift time: 2887 ms

js time: 13 ms

flutter time: 10 ms

Swift code:

```
    var x = 0
    let start = Date()
    for i in 0..<10000000 {
        x += i
    }
    let time = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(start) * 1000)
    print("time: \(time) ms") //time: 2887 ms
```

JS code:

```
var x = 0
const start = (+new Date())
for(var i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
    x += i
}
const time = new Date() - start;
console.log('time: ' + time + 'ms') //time: 13ms
```

Flutter code:

```
  int x = 0;
  var start = DateTime.now();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i ++) {
    x += i;
  }
  var time = DateTime.now().difference(start).inMilliseconds;
  print('time: ' + time.toString() + 'ms'); //time: 10ms
```

Comment: In a compiled program or in a playground? And maybe you can shave of a millisecond by using CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() so you don’t need to cast ;)

Comment: Runs in 4 ms on my MacBook if compiled with "Release" configuration, i.e. with optimizations enabled.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much for your help. I solved this problem according to the settings you said.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Running in the iOS app, this problem has been solved, thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: If you have a solution to your problem, you should answer your own question, so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MartinR.

Solution:
Need to set Build Configuration to "Release" to enable optimization.